# React Intl FormattedNumber with the currency symbol before, not after

Tags: reactjs, internationalization

I am using FormattedNumber from React Intl in a big React project that has the capability for many different languages.

Here is a Currency component I made so that I can easily insert a formatted currency into my views:

```
import {FormattedNumber} from 'react-intl';

const Currency = (props) => {

    const currency = props.currency;
    const minimum = props.minimumFractionDigits || 2;
    const maximum = props.maximumFractionDigits || 2;
    return <FormattedNumber
                    value={props.amount}
                    style="currency"
                    currency={currency}
                    minimumFractionDigits={minimum}
                    maximumFractionDigits={maximum}
    />;
};

export default Currency;
```

The component works great. And, it works as expected. In English - when `currency` is `GBP` - an amount is formatted as such:

```
£4.00
```

In German - when `currency` is `EUR` - it's formatted as such:

```
4,00€
```

However, I need to format the amount differently in a particular case. So, what I'm looking for is the Euro coming before the amount, like so:

```
€4,00
```

Is this possible with FormattedNumber? I don't want to have to manually reformat the formatted number if I can avoid it.

Comment: Looks like there is a similar open issue on this: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/issues/534. According to their current [docs](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattednumber), this is not possible to adjust. Bummer.

Comment: Thanks, the example of how to remove decimals in the currency display helped me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could wrap your `FormattedNumber` with an `IntlProvider` component with the appropriate locale prop, like this:

```jsx
<IntlProvider locale='en'>
  <FormattedNumber
    value={props.amount}
    style="currency"
    currency={props.currency} />
</IntlProvider>
```

Maybe the 'en' file isn't still the right, cause it will use a period instead of a comma, but you can either look for a locale ([see here](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki#the-react-intl-package)) that provides the correct format or just write one yourself (to stay simple by copying the en locale and replacing the period with the comma in the respective line).

Answer (score 7):

You can specify a custom, named formats via the `formats` prop on `<IntlProvider>`. There's also `defaultFormats` which are used with the `defaultLocale` in the fallback case because the `formats` might be dependent on the `locale`. Here's an example with `<FormattedMessage>` and `<FormattedNumber>` using a custom named number format `USD`:

```
const formats = {
    number: {
        TRY: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'TRY'
        },
        USD: {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: 'USD'
        }
    }
};

<IntlProvider locale='en' messages={{
        price: 'This product costs {price, number, USD}'
    }}
    formats={formats}
    defaultFormats={formats}
>
    <FormattedMessage id={'price'} values={{price: 1000}}/>
    <FormattedNumber value={1000} format='USD'/>
</IntlProvider>
```